# Take commands(password) from string and set as InputStream to Unix servers in Java (JSCH)

Tags: java, linux, shell, unix, jsch

Almost similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846514/change-unix-password-with-java) topic, but here I am not a superuser to use --stdin.

So I found an other way round, I would open a "shell" in background and give input to shell via a `String` through `InputStream`

I made a code like below:

```
String s = "cd bin\n";

byte bb[] = s.getBytes();

InputStream intt = new ByteArrayInputStream(bb);

channel.setInputStream(new FilterInputStream(intt) {
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        return in.read(b, off, (len > 1024 ? 1024 : len));
    }
});
```

Now this works perfectly when I want to execute only one command but I want to give multiple commands, for which I am facing issue.

Any suggestions?

Regards,

Ishan

Comment: just an update, Are you clear with the explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to question I asked, don't know if its a full proof solution since I tested with limited period of time and I did it beast way I can.

```
channel = session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
((ChannelExec) channel).setPty(true);
```

In the command string

```
String command = "(echo old_password; echo new_password; echo new_password) | passwd username";
```

or if not a superuser then,

```
String command = "(echo old_password; echo new_password; echo new_password) | passwd"
```

That is it ;)

regards,

icr