# How to change password of AIX system through java program?

Tags: java, putty, aix, jsch

My requirement is to change password of `AIX server` through java program.
I used `jsch library`.

With `jsch` I can execute commands like `ls -ltr`, etc. **But** for `passwd` command, nothing is happening.

Kindly post your answer.

Comment: Take a look to this: [Take commands(password) from string and set as InputStream to Unix servers in Java (JSCH)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18456644/4359029)

Comment: "Nothing is happening" - That's pretty vague. For sure the command at least outputs some error message or exit code.

Comment: Also, where's your code?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : Nothing means No password changed but exit with sucess code - 0.

Comment: @tomloprod when i used jsch as said then it is asking for password : Changing password for "User"
User's Old password:  XXXXXX . But I already entered password so why it is asking again.